# calling to method in retrofit response

Tags: android, mongodb, retrofit, retrofit2

i have two methods in my api which i have to call independently because each of them return a different object and actually when i tested it worked perfectly but the problem is when i have to test it a second time it bugs . and I want to make sure my code is correct or not .

```
   IFiche IFiche = APIClient.getClient().create(IFiche.class);

                        String ItemsSP = GetItemSelectedSP();
                        String ItemsAntc = GetItemSelectedAntc();

                        IFiche.add(Double.parseDouble(age.getText().toString()), Double.parseDouble(EVA.getText().toString())
                                , ItemsSP, ItemsAntc, motif.getText().toString(), total_score,Integer.parseInt(ID))
                                .enqueue(new Callback<FichePatient>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(Call<FichePatient> call, Response<FichePatient> response) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Succees", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        IUser IUser = APIClient.getClient().create(IUser.class);
                                        IUser.affecterliste_fiche(Integer.parseInt(ID), Integer.parseInt(response.body().getId()),
                                                total_score).enqueue(new Callback<Users>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onResponse(Call<Users> call, Response<Users> response) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HIIIIII", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                response.body().setLastScore(total_score);
                                                Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NavigationActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(Call<Users> call, Throwable t)
                                            {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NOOO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                Log.v("TAG!!!!!!!!!!", "error   " + t.getMessage());
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(Call<FichePatient> call, Throwable t) {
                                        Log.v("TAG!!!!!!!!!!!", "error   " + t.getMessage());
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "erreur", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: what is the error you get for second time?

Comment: it crashes the entire application

Comment: is it possible to call another method in the first on response like i did ?

Comment: Why don't have onSuccess() ?

Comment: i got the same problem

Comment: Please post the latest code with the crash log.

Comment: this is the error that i got , and it turns out that the problem came from alertdialog , and i'm seraching how to relsove this problem . E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.myapplication 55.Triage Activity has leaked window DecorView@2ec2e67